# nested ngFor performance on large dataset

Tags: ngfor

I've created a scheduling app that allows users to add other users and view there availability. The app show available times as light grey, non-available as gray, and striped out as a global blackout. I have a 3D array of objects called
timeblockViewModels[][] that I'm using to store all this data. Then I use two nest ngFor loops to loops through all the data and draw it on the screen.

It seems to work fine for 1-5 users but any more than that and I start to get pretty steep delays. For as many users as I have in the screenshot below it takes about 30 seconds. That's in Chrome. IE using polyfill and on my iPad tests it can take over a minute or two.

I know that I'm abusing the ngFor here and need to find a better way. When I mocked this up as pure html it loads just fine. Are there any options I can take to improve this?

[image]